# Optimize DB2 SQL SUM query

Tags: sql, optimization, db2

I'm trying to add a row that indicate the total for a bunch of data. For example:

```
ISAAC      25000
Jane       18000
-----------------
TOTAL    43000
```

My current way of achieving this is using a sub-query which looks like this:

```
select name, salary
from employee
union all 
select 'TOTAL', sum(salary) 
from
(
   select name, salary from employee
)
```

I am wondering if there is optimized sql query which returns me a single row that indicate the total.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rollup` and luckily db2 supports rollup

```
SELECT 
  name,  
  sum(salary) as sal
FROM 
  table 
GROUP BY ROLLUP 
  name
```

Result

```
|   NAME | SAL         |
------------------------
|  ISAAC |       25000 |
|   Jane |       18000 |
|    -   |       43000 |
```

### **[REFER](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059215.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Err... what's wrong with just: `SELECT SUM(salary) FROM employee`?

And you could try creating an index on `salary`, to [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) the query above.

BTW, SQL is for querying, not for display, so don't try to "format" the result in the SQL itself. That's the job for the presentation layer.